# Updating table data where multiple rows might have become obsolete

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, pymysql

I have an application where i can create and edit recipes consisting of ingredients and their amounts. This information is supposed to be saved in a relational database (probably MySQL or SQLite). I have a table storing recipes with an auto_increment primary key and another table where i save the ingredients and amounts, referencing the first table via a foreign key constraint.

Now i want to write the updating code inside my application. I save the recipe id's in my recipe objects, so i can reference that quite easily. But how do i properly update the ingredients and the amounts? Multiple rows of the second table might have become obsolete and have to be deleted, and some just need to be updated (when the amount was changed).

The simplest solution I came up with would be just deleting all the rows referring to my current recipe and re-inserting them. Is that an acceptable approach, or is there a pattern/best-practice for this kind of problem?

---

Note: I know i could just save the ingredients and amounts in varchar stringlist, but i would like to work with some kind of table structure.

---

**Edit:** The tables CREATE code:

```
CREATE TABLE `recipe` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `recipe_ingredients` (
    `recipe_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ingredient` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `amount` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `measurement_unit` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    INDEX `recipe_id` (`recipe_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `recipe_ingredients_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`recipe_id`) REFERENCES `recipe` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `recipe_ingredients_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`recipe_id`) REFERENCES `recipe` (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Show us some code that you have tried and give us some sample table data please.

Comment: What are you using for the business layer of your code? Programming language, framework, etc.?

Comment: @dfundako I didn't try anything yet, but i had a project at my side job, where i used the "delete everything and re-insert"-strategy and that worked, but i feel like there should be a more performant way. Added the create code of the tables.

Comment: @TomH I am using Python with PyMySQL, no framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an auto_increment primary key to your ingredient table.  Then when your application issues an update, you can identify which ingredient is being updated by its primary key.

I would add the PK like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `recipe_ingredients` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `recipe_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ingredient` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `amount` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `measurement_unit` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    INDEX `recipe_id` (`recipe_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `recipe_ingredients_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`recipe_id`) REFERENCES `recipe` (`id`),    
)
```

In your UI, you would loop through the ingredients and display them on separate rows, with the ingredient id being associated with each row.  It might look something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ingredient</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Units</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tdata>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='hidden' id='ingredient1_id' value='1' />
        <input type='text' id='ingredient1_name' value="salt" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' id='ingredient1_amount' value="2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' id='ingredient1_unit' value="tsp" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='hidden' id='ingredient2_id' value='2' />
        <input type='text' id='ingredient2_name' value="flour" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' id='ingredient2_amount' value="3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='text' id='ingredient2_unit' value="cups" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tdata>
</table>
```

Now if a user edits or deletes the salt row, you know it was the ingredient with id 1, and you can identify it in your database.

Comment: I don't quite get that answer. Should i create another `ingredient` table, or just add an auto_increment id key to the existing `recipe_ingredient` table? How would you save that in an application? Create another class/struct to hold ingredient information, or just save all the information in a list (something like [ingredient_name, amount, measurement_unit, db_id])?

Comment: Add an auto_increment id key to the existing `recipe_ingredient` table.  How does your application work?  I assumed you were retrieving your ingredient list and displaying it to the user in some sort of table (which could include the ingredient key).  Are you doing something "simpler", like just having the user enter a single text field of ingredients, and parsing out the ingredients by row?

Comment: I have no user interface yet, im just trying to learn how to properly architect software building my application up from the bottom. The idea is to have the user enter ingredients via text fields, one at a time. They are stored in a dictionary, so i can search for recipes with specific ingredients quite easily, the key being the ingredient name, and the value being a tuple of the amount, unit and other info i need.